How to prevent Kubernetes log rotation from compressing files?
Hi we have Kubernetes log rotation setup to rotate every 100MB. We have a Filebeat daemonset reading the /var/log/pods folder.
That works all nice and dandy except when we experience large volume, logs start to rotate and zip at Filebeat continues the rotated uncompressed file. And we miss logs.
Is there a way to tell Kubernetes to rotate but not compress? Or a way not to lose any logs from the rotation?
Update:
The only configs I have set for Kubelet are containerLogMaxFiles: 10 and
containerLogMaxSize: 100Mi In the Kubelete config. As far as log rotate I have looked in /etc/logrotate.d and I don't see anything specific to /var/log/pods
To be clear the logs in /var/logs/pods are being rotated by Kubelet. using the above setting in the Kubelete config.
Also checking the logrotate status output at /var/lib/logrotate/status there is no /var/log/pods/...
Update we have filebeat reading /var/log/containers sim linked file instead of /var/log/pods

Try adding delaycompress to the logrotate configuration folder /var/log/pods, which may help to solve the problem. Refer to die.net’s logrotate(8) - Linux man page for more details.
Also could you please update your question with your YAML configuration file to further check on this issue. If you want to prevent compression, you can remove the compress option from your logrotate configuration file, which you may use as the default option.

Hi the only configs I have set for Kubelet are containerLogMaxFiles: 10 and
containerLogMaxSize: 100Mi In the Kubelete config. As far as log rotate I have looked in /etc/logrotate.d and I don't see anything specific to /var/log/pods

Is it possible there a global config somewhere?

Also checking the logrotate status output at /var/lib/logrotate/status there is no /var/log/pods/...

I don't see where logrotate config is, any hints where I can check?

You can check the logrotate configuration in / etc / logrotate.conf or within / etc / logrotate.d / directory. Check these locations for files that might define global rotate  settings affecting all log files on the system, including kubernetes logs. Refer to this documentation .Also refer to the similar github issue for more details.

Ok so, /etc/logrotate.d has alternatives  apport  apt  bootlog  btmp  dpkg  netdata  rsyslog  ubuntu-advantage-tools  ufw  unattended-upgrades  wtmp I checked inside nothing specific for kubernetes. For /etc/logrotate.conf #compress is commented and apart it pointing to /etc/logrotate.d/ none of the setting coincide with the behaviour of Kubelet rotation.
To be clear https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#log-rotation these 2 settings mentioned don't seem to have anything to do with logrotate or work in tandem or config logrotate somewhere somehow?

Also the github issue you linked is related to crashing containers and restarted containers. My issue is around live container with lots of logs and where the logrotate is configured because I can't find any logrotate config what so ever.

Are you sure that logrotate is still the preffered method with latest Kubernetes like 1.27.x and up?

The main logrotate configuration file is located at /etc/logrotate.conf.Typically, the directory has a configuration file that logrotate reads in order to rotate the system logs for your syslog service. This documentation includes commands that are comparable to those in logrotate.conf, as well as entries for other system logs.

You are not understanding. Logrotate is not configured anywhere for Kubernetes, Kubelete or /var/log/pods. I mentioned it above /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrotate.d/ have no configurations what so ever that correspond to the way the logs are being rotated for Kubelet in /var/logs/pods/ In fact I'm starting to think that since Kubernetes 1.21 the introduced log rotation in Kubelet. With the settings that I also indicated above. In fact go read the lates Logging Architecture of Kubernetes. You will see for yourself.

I think the log rotation is a bespoke part of the kubelet code i.e. it does not use logrotate
kubelet code

Yes I know. But it's kinda sorta documented. The docs mention it. So to disable it don't include a size and manually setup log rotate?
